# How to call the root/parent of a struct

Tags: c

This is how my struct looks like:

```
struct Coordinate{
    int x;
    int y;
    int steps;
    struct Coordinate *left;
    struct Coordinate *right;
    struct Coordinate *up;
    struct Coordinate *down;
}*root;

typedef struct Coordinate *Coor;
```

I am making a tree of many structs like this and at a certain point i would like to check the data (x,y) of the root of a struct.

How do i get the data of this struct root (parent)?

*** EDIT ***

This is my all code (not that long):

```
//
//  main.c
//  C-3
//
//  Created by Nimrod Shai on 6/21/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Nimrod Shai. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#define length 2

struct Coordinate{
    int x;
    int y;
    int steps;
    struct Coordinate *left;
    struct Coordinate *right;
    struct Coordinate *up;
    struct Coordinate *down;
}*root;

typedef struct Coordinate *Coor;

int isValidCoordinate(struct Coordinate *aCoordinate, int x, int y, int map[length][length]){

    if ((x >= 0) && (x <= length) && (y >= 0) && (y <= length) && !map[y][x]) {


        for (int i = 0; i < aCoordinate -> steps; i++) {
            aCoordinate = aCoordinate -> father;
            if (aCoordinate->x == x && aCoordinate->y == y) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

}

Coor insertDataToTree(Coor root, int x, int y, int map[length][length], int steps){

    steps++;

    if (root == NULL) {
        root = (Coor)malloc(sizeof(Coor));
        root->x = x;
        root->y = y;
        root->steps = steps;
        root -> left = root -> right = root -> up = root -> down = NULL;

    }



    //left
    if (isValidCoordinate(root,root -> x - 1, root -> y, map)) {
        printf("f");
        root->left = insertDataToTree(root -> left, x - 1, y, map,steps);
    }
    //right
    if (isValidCoordinate(root,root -> x + 1, root -> y, map)) {
        printf("f");
        root->right = insertDataToTree(root -> right, x + 1, y, map,steps);
    }
    //up
    if (isValidCoordinate(root,root -> x, root -> y - 1, map)) {
        printf("f");
        root->up = insertDataToTree(root -> up, x, y - 1, map,steps);
    }
    //down
    if (isValidCoordinate(root,root -> x, root -> y + 1, map)) {
        printf("f");
        root->down = insertDataToTree(root -> down, x, y + 1, map,steps);
    }

    Coor ggg = NULL;
    return ggg;
}




int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int map[length][length] = {
        {0,0},
        {0,0}
    };

    struct Coordinate startPoint;
    startPoint.x = 0;
    startPoint.y = 0;
    startPoint.steps = -1;

    insertDataToTree(root, startPoint.x, startPoint.y, map, startPoint.steps);

    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The purpose of this code is mapping the entire paths inside a matrix from a certain start point into a tree with branches=paths to all possible points.

issue is - one of the checks i need to do on a point i'm adding to this tree is that it's coordinate isn't repeating up in its branch (don't mind if it appears in other branches).

but i don't know how to get the values of the root of a certain struct.

I hope i'm clearer now, and that someone can help me with this awful syntax… (i usually program in objective-C).

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: If you're given a `Coor *`, there's no way to find its parent node from the data in the `Coor` structure.  If you need that, you'll have to add `struct Coordinate *parent` to the structure, and initialize it appropriately.

Comment: I thought about doing that but i didn't know where is the right place to initialise that parent variable

Answer (score 0):

`root->x` and `root->y`, assuming you've allocated it properly in some other code you're not showing us.